# Set array of parameters to hibernate query language

Tags: hibernate, hql

Currently the query takes in a single reportID to return the results. Now if I want to pass multiple reportIDs and return the o/p in just 1 call to the DB, how do I do that?

```
String queryText = "from com.abc.domain.bcd.Report report  where report.reportID in :reportId";

    Query query = SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryText.toString());

    query.setParameter("reportID", reportId);

    query.list();
```

I tried passing as an arrayList but no luck. Got the error below

```
List<String> reportID= new ArrayList<String>();
    reportID.add("aaa");
    reportID.add("bbb");
```

java.util.ArrayList incompatible with java.lang.String

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this one

```
 query.setParameterList("reportID", new Object[]{"aaa","bbb"});
```

Comment: how to pass String[] reportID as parameter