# Validate occurrence of object in Array as Parameter in HQL query

Tags: hibernate, hql

How do I check for the existence of an object in an arraylist of instances of the same class in a HQL query?

For the ease of understanding I'll paste the entire method in which I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
   public List<Relation> findRelations(List<Organisation> subjectOrganisations) {
    return emFactory.get()
            .createQuery("FROM Relation rel WHERE rel.subject.id in (SELECT r.id FROM RelationEntityOrganisation r where r.organisation in :subjectOrganisations)", Relation.class)
            .setParameter("subjectOrganisations", subjectOrganisations).getResultList();
}
```

I think the problem is caused by me trying to check the existence of an organisation instance in an ArrayList in an illegal way namely the "`where r.organisation in :subjectOrganisations`" part of the query.

This is the Error stacktrace that I get when I try to run the query:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ) near line 1, column 192 [FROM com.company.you.server.domain.entity.Relation rel WHERE rel.subject.id in (SELECT r.id FROM com.company.you.server.domain.entity.RelationEntityOrganisation r where r.organisation in )]
>       at 
>   (...)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ) near line 1, column 192 [FROM com.Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ) near line 1, column 192 [FROM com.company.you.server.domain.entity.Relation rel WHERE rel.subject.id in (SELECT r.id FROM com.company.you.server.domain.entity.RelationEntityOrganisation r where r.organisation in )]
>   (...)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1254)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
>       ... 60 more

I have already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512109/set-array-of-parameters-to-hibernate-query-language) article but it doesn't answer my question because I want to inject an array of the type ArrayList into the HQL.

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: It seems your query doesn't have any parameter: the exeption says it ends with `where r.organisation in )`. Are you sure you're showing us the actual code that you're executing?

Comment: It is possible that the class that uses this service method passes an empty array. Does this mean that HQL will throw an exception when the array is empty?

Comment: I notice that whenever I make sure the array isn't empty it works. So the code I wrote is fine. Thanks for the suggestion! But what do I do with this question then.. ? Do I remove it from Stackoverflow?